How to set up an nx workspace with angular 14
I am trying to migrate to an nx workspace. I have 2 apps and 2 libraries all using angular version 14. I am currently locked into this angular version as I am using ionic 5. I've tried multiple ways to set up a workspace but no luck so far.
I tried latest nx workspace and enforce the angular version
npx create-nx-workspace@latest my-workspace --preset=angular --angularVersion=14 -> angular version was 18
npx create-nx-workspace@15.7.0 my-workspace and then added angular apps, but the angular version was 15.
I would appreciate if you can point me in some direction. Thanks!
I tried latest nx workspace and enforce the angular version
npx create-nx-workspace@latest my-workspace --preset=angular --angularVersion=14 -> angular version was 18
npx create-nx-workspace@15.7.0 my-workspace and then added angular apps, but the angular version was 15.
Expected outcome would be to have the angular version 14 in the nx workspace so that I can add the apps and libraries.

The version of nx workspace determines the angular version. You can look here to find out which nx version aligns with your angular version:
https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/documents/angular-nx-version-matrix
then generate the workspace with the desired version: create-nx-workspace@14.6.0 my-workspace
